# Plotting a discontinuous function using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Say I want to plot the function `|sin(x)|` and its derivative, which has a discontinuity at `x = 0`, using `pgfplots`. How can I handle the discontinuity? What I'd like to happen is for the red line below to end at `(0,-1)`, then jump to `(0,1)` and continue normally from there. My main issue here is having two points with the x-coordinate `0`, I think.

I do *not* want to have two separate plots (as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373497/48973), which is actually about division), as this would mess with automatic selection of the line style and other features of `pgfplots` (e.g. a single entry in the legend).

---

If I read the documentation correctly, I could achieve the desired effect by explicitly providing the coordinates `(0,-1), (0,nan), (0,1)` and setting `unbounded coords=jump`, but I want to plot the function without specifying all the coordinates. Specifying the coordinate of the discontinuity is fine, of course.

---

A starting point:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        trig format plots=rad,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=201,
        no markers,
        xtick={-pi, 0, pi},
        xticklabels={\(-\pi\), \(0\), \(\pi\)},
        ytick={-1, 0, 1},
        grid=major,
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
      ]
    \addplot {abs(sin(x))};
    \addplot {sign(x) * cos(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63028

Comment: @Lazysquirrel That answer does not seem to use `pgfplots`.

Comment: You are looking at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63028) by Peter Grill, right? It does have `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `axis` environments, how is it not using `pgfplots`?

Comment: @Lazysquirrel Oops, sorry. Somehow jumped to the other answer first.. The answer you are referring to does use separate `\addplot` commands to draw the different segments of the plot, though, which is not what I want, as outlined above.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Add `unbounded coords=jump` and plot `(x==0?nan:sign(x) * cos(x))`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} %<-consider adding
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        trig format plots=rad,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=201,
        no markers,
        xtick={-pi, 0, pi},
        xticklabels={\(-\pi\), \(0\), \(\pi\)},
        ytick={-1, 0, 1},
        grid=major,
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        unbounded coords=jump
      ]
    \addplot {abs(sin(x))};
    \addplot {(x==0?nan:sign(x) * cos(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: For the sake of "if its doable let's do it even if it is crazy", here is a version that adds some jump marks. This is a compromise between subverting the plot handler (which is possible but even crazier) and just adding public global macros (which I thing one *really* has to avoid, if possible).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgfpush[1]{\pgfutil@pushmacro#1}
\newcommand\pgfpop[1]{\pgfutil@popmacro#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        trig format plots=rad,
        domain=-pi:pi,
        samples=201,
        no markers,
        xtick={-pi, 0, pi},
        xticklabels={\(-\pi\), \(0\), \(\pi\)},
        ytick={-1, 0, 1},
        grid=major,
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        jump threshold/.initial=1
      ]
    \addplot {abs(sin(x))};
    \edef\isfirstpoint{1}
    \pgfpush\isfirstpoint
    \addplot+[scatter,
     scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%           
            \pgfpop\isfirstpoint                        
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}%
            \ifnum\isfirstpoint=0
              \pgfpop\mylasty
              \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(abs(\mylasty-\myy)<\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/jump threshold}?0:1)}
              \ifnum\itest=1\relax
                \pgfpop\mylastx
                \draw[fill=white] 
                 (axis direction cs:\mylastx-\myx,\mylasty-\myy) circle[radius=2pt]
                 (axis direction cs:0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
              \fi   
            \fi
            \edef\isfirstpoint{0}%
            \pgfpush\isfirstpoint
            \edef\mylasty{\myy}%
            \pgfpush\mylasty
            \edef\mylastx{\myx}%
            \pgfpush\mylastx
            }
    ] {(x==0?nan:sign(x) * cos(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could argue that subverting the plot handler is a better option because then the user does not have to explicitly specify a jump threshold. I do not have any good counter-argument except that I am too lazy.

Comment: This is close. Any way to add the points `(0,-1)` and `(0,1)`?

Comment: @schtandard I added something that does that.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have been clearer. I did not mean adding jump marks at the ends of the line. I meant for the line to actually reach the points `(0,-1)` and `(0,1)`. Right now, it stops just short of that (and, accordingly, the marks in your addendum are off-center).

Comment: @schtandard The gap depends on the number of samples, of course. In this case the function has slope zero around the discontinuity, but this will not be generally true. (But I can definitely move the empty circles to the right positions, this is not the challenge here.)